# what should I do to make the aes256 encrypt result keep the same with typescript and java

Tags: java, typescript, aes

I am encrypt the same text `123` with AES256 using typescript and java, this is the typescript function:

```
  const handleSubmit1 = () => {
    const key = '123'
    const iv = '1234567812345678'
    const cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("123", CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
        iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv), 
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
    })
    let result= cipher.toString()
    // FgMtDtbBHk5MoEfIJLxmIw==
    console.log(result)
  }
```

and this is the java function to do the same thing:

```
public static String encrypt() {
        try {
            MessageDigest sha = null;
            byte[] bytes = "1234567812345678".getBytes();
            ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(bytes);
            try {
                key = "123".getBytes("UTF-8");
                sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                key = sha.digest(key);
                String s = new String(key);
                secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal("123".getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

To my surprise, the two function have different results, the java version return `wrmBgoJRATOqL5qKCsN/wA==` and the typescript version return `FgMtDtbBHk5MoEfIJLxmIw==`. why encrypt the same content with same key and iv have different results? Am I missing something? I have searched from internet and told me that `PKCS5Padding` and `PKCS7Padding` did not effect the result. what should I do to fix this and make the two language with the same action? I also tried to sha the key in typescript like this:

```
const handleSubmit1 = () => {
    const key = '123'
    const iv = '1234567812345678'
    const SHA256 = CryptoJS.SHA256(key).toString();
    const cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("123", CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(SHA256), {
        iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv), 
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
    })
    let result= cipher.toString()
    // FgMtDtbBHk5MoEfIJLxmIw==
    console.log(result)
  }
```

still could not make the results match. Any sugguestion is appreciated.

Comment: Decrypting the Java result in the TS code (or viceversa) throws a wrong result?

Comment: I want to make the typescript encrypt content keep the same with the java, if not, the java could not decrypt the encrypt string from client. @JettoMartínez what should I do to make the encrypt keep the same with the same parameter?

Comment: I checked my code and found all the parameter keep the same but get the different result, that make me confusing, the typescript encrypt content must keep the same with the server side so that I could decrypt the content in server side. @JettoMartínez

Comment: The Java code uses the SHA256 value of 123 as key, while the JavaScript code directly applies 123 as key (the latter is an invalid AES key but accepted due to a CryptoJS bug).

Comment: how to tweak my code to make the two function keep the same, I am thinking for a while but still no clue fo find out the solution.@Topaco

Comment: Replace `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key)` with `CryptoJS.SHA256(key)`. Also, note that a digest as key derivation is insecure, better apply a proven key derivation function like PBKDF2. And also a static IV is insecure.

Comment: Thank you, the problem fixed by replace what you said. @Topaco